# adobe-flashplugin active and working in Firefox, not in Chromium

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium, 17.04, adobe

When enabling Canonical Partner repositories, and installing adobe-flashplugin from them using apt, the plugin functions fine on Firefox, but is disabled by chromium.

[image: about:version screen]

That's my about:version screen on firefox, saying that flash is disabled.

I can't find a way to navigate to about:plugins, or chrome://plugins/, like many answers for this problem reference when working with older versions of the OS.

As I mentioned before, Firefox seems to have no problem rendering Flash content.

Comment: It may be due to [this change](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/01/29/google-removes-plugin-controls-from-chrome/). What's the result if you visit [this page](http://get.adobe.com/se/flashplayer/about/) from Chromium?

Comment: Page loads fine, but the window where they _would_ tell you your flash version has the grey puzzle piece, and any other flash checking website tells me that it isn't installed.

Comment: The other page I linked to says that you should be able to control Flash via `chrome://settings`, but since I don't use Chromium I can't tell exactly how.

Comment: There was a toggle to allow flash globally, and only important content, flipping them around doesn't seem to be affecting anything.