# adobe-flashplugin blocked on local SWF files after latest firefox (v. 55.0.2) update on Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: firefox, flash

This problem is somehow complementary to that posed by question [adobe-flashplugin active and working in Firefox, not in Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935306/adobe-flashplugin-active-and-working-in-firefox-not-in-chromium). After the latest xenial update, local access to an SWF file was blocked, both in Firefox and in Ubuntu. Then I uninstalled the flashplugin-installer package and installed adobe-flashplugin one instead. This is supposed to install the Adobe Flash Player plugins compatible with both Chromium and Mozilla based web browsers. The replacement was effective for Chromium but not for Firefox. In the latter, the plugin appears to be installed and always active, the check on the Adobe site says it's the latest version (26) and the animation test works fine, but opening the local file doesn't work. Please note that the problem only arises with local opening of SWF files, remote access to the same files uploaded on a trusted site is no problem. I had applied the solution to an earlier instance of this problem according to  the top answer to question [Why can't Firefox run local .swf files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/478169/why-cant-firefox-run-local-swf-files), but that solution doesn't work anymore. Is there anything that can be done to find out the cause of the problem or a workaround to it?

Comment: Have you tried the other answer?

Comment: Yes (sorry, I forgot to mention that). Neither that works.